# Limit on the size of Azure table property that can be indexed by search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have Azure Search indexing an Azure table from Table Storage, including multiple properties.

I have found a case where if one of the columns has a string content of 487 chars it gets "ignored" and the corresponding search field returns null.

The search index field is setup as follows:

```
new Field() { Name = Columns.OwnerAliases, Type = DataType.String, IsSearchable = true, IsRetrievable = true }
```

I don't believe the problem here is any limit other some limit on the size of the content of the table property. Other records with smaller contents on this property are being indexed correctly.

So my question is: Is there any limit on the size of a table property that can be indexed?

Note that the indexer completes without any error or warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit on indexing Azure table properties, beyond those imposed by Table storage itself (64 kb). A string with 487 characters won't be affected by any Azure Search limits either. Double check your search query and that the indexer actually got to the row in question (based on the change tracking state reported in indexer execution status)